# Nested loop problem in python while working with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, boto3

I am trying to created a nested loop to load multiple files in an s3 bucket and concatenate them into a single dataframe. I am having trouble in arranging the nested loops in order to do this.
Here  is my code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import boto3
import io
client = boto3.client('s3')
    var = "filename"
    filenumber = ["/0", "/1", "/2","/3"]

    for j in range(len(filenumber)):
        response = client.list_objects(Bucket="bucketname", Prefix="subfolder/%s" % (var + filenumber[j]))

        df_list = []
        json_buffer = io.StringIO()

        for file in response["Contents"]:
            obj = client.get_object(Bucket="bucketname", Key=file["Key"])
            obj_df = pd.read_json(obj["Body"])
            df_list.append(obj_df)
        df = pd.concat(df_list)
    df.to_json(json_buffer)
```

On keeping `df = pd.concat(df_list)` inside the outer loop, I get the error: `DataFrame index must be unique for orient='columns'`
If i keep the line outside the outer loop, I only get the last iteration file from the list ie. "/3" loaded into the dataframe.

any help/suggestions are much appreciated. Sorry if my question needs editing, kinda new to stackoverflow.

Comment: DataFrame is a mutable variable. Try changing both lines `obj_df = pd.read_json(obj["Body"])` and `df_list.append(obj_df)` to `df_list.append(pd.read_json(obj["Body"]))`

Comment: Thanks for the response! But the loop is still just returning the last iteration ie. "/3". I want all the iterations one by one to be appended to the dataframe.

Comment: Oh. Initialize df_list (`df_list = []`) before the loop and concat it after the range loop.

Comment: I tried that, but to no avail, so i stripped down my code and trying to visualize it using http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html... i know nested loops are usually a bad idea but the results i'm getting are extremely bad

Answer (score 1):

You get that error when your dataframe has a non-unique index or (repeated) values. Since it doesn't look like you're using the index, you could create a new one by using the following command:

`df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

or

If you want to remove the previous index.

`df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

For a deeper understanding and referring to [http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#set-reset-index](http://%20http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#set-reset-index) would be useful

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried that but its still returning the last iteration only.
Any suggestions on what i'm doing wrong here? Maybe i'm placing the statements in the wrong positions?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

var = "filename"

filenumber = ["0", "1", "2","3"]

df_list = []
for subdir in filenumber:
    response = client.list_objects(Bucket="bucketname", Prefix=f"subfolder/{var}/{subdir}")

    for file in response["Contents"]:
        obj = client.get_object(Bucket="bucketname", Key=file["Key"])
        print(file["Key"])
        df_list.append(pd.read_json(obj["Body"]))
df = pd.concat(df_list)
result = df.to_json(orient="records")
parsed = json.loads(result)
print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4))
```